# Is there a way to query direct module dependencies with gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, c++-modules

Given a module

```cpp
// a-m.cc
export module A;

import B;
import C;

import "D.h";

...
```

Is there a way of invoking gcc (similar to what -M does for headers) that will list the direct dependencies on other modules and imported headers (i.e. B, C, and "D.h")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [Edit]

It seems we can invoke gcc with the flag `-MMD`, which also tracks module dependencies. Given an example project I have, I generated it like this:

```cpp
// partition.cpp
export module partition;

import :partition1;
export import :partition2;
export import :partition3;

export void Hello1() { _Hello1(); }
```

For some reason I needed to compile the module partitions before compiling the primary module interface (file shown above), but perhaps this can somehow be circumvented. I compile the above file like this:

```
g++-11 -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -c -MMD partition.cpp
```

This generates a file `partition.d` listing module dependencies:

```
partition.o gcm.cache/partition.gcm: partition.cpp
partition.o gcm.cache/partition.gcm: partition:partition3.c++m \
 partition:partition2.c++m partition:partition1.c++m
partition.c++m: gcm.cache/partition.gcm
.PHONY: partition.c++m
gcm.cache/partition.gcm:| partition.o
CXX_IMPORTS += partition:partition3.c++m partition:partition2.c++m \
 partition:partition1.c++m
```

Seems promising, but more research is needed.

#### My own solution

I have written / am writing such a tool. It can be found on github: https://github.com/alexpanter/cpp_module_parser.

It is unfinished, but is actually working. If interest is shown, I will continue expanding it.

I also have a bundle of small example projects with modules, intended as a starting point for further research: https://github.com/alexpanter/modules_testing

#### GCC

GCC looks for precompiled modules (BMI's) in a local directory: `./gcm.cache/usr/include/c++/11/iostream.gcm` or (for local module units) `./gcm.cache/,/my-module.gcm`.

If user code imports a module, the the precompiled module unit *must* be already present in this directory, otherwise compilation will fail.
It is, unfortunately (at least currently) not possible to specify another directory, or a custom directory per build command. This would be very practical, and I'm hoping the GCC devs will add it at some point. The `gcm.cache/` directory is used by the default module mapper. It is possible to create one's own module mapper, but from the reading I have done this sounds like a complicated procedure since a module mapper is essentially a web server:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Module-Mapper.html
- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1184r2.pdf

#### Comparison

Comparing to @Laserskjöld's answer, I think collecting preprocessor output would be a viable solution as well, since module import/export commands are recognized by the preprocessor. However, I do not think it is a *good* solution since it would be much slower than a tool such as what I have written. An example:

```cpp
module;

#include <iostream>

export module mymodule;

import myothermodule;

export
{
    [...]
}
```

After preprocessing, this file will be ~100000 lines long, and all lines need to be processed by the preprocessor. But with my tool (or one that is potentially more efficient), only the first 9 lines will be read by the module-parsing tool, rest of the file will be ignored.
Besides, the point of having modules is to be less dependent upon the preprocessor.

Comment: You can actually use a plain text file as a module mapper. See, for example, what I did for bazel support: https://github.com/rnburn/rules_cc_module/blob/main/util/driver/gcc.py#L17

Comment: @RyanBurn that's an interesting concept, but I can't get it to work - do you have an example Makefile and a couple of cpp files so I can reproduce? Also, do you have to specify a line for each module? Because I would much rather use `-fmodule-mapper` to specify an additional import directory. Per-file management seems a bit tricky at a larger scale..

Comment: That repo has a docker image you can invoke to get a reproducible environment. And yes, the file version of module mapper is per module. More granular, per-file management is usually better for larger scale projects.

Comment: @RyanBurn Ahhh, I have never used docker before :P But thanks for the advice, I might check that out some day. I'm very interested in modules! Though I would prefer to have a tool auto-deduct file dependencies. Currently using premake, and working on a proposal for adding gcc module support - it will likely take some time, though.

Comment: @RyanBurn I tried to follow the [instructions](https://github.com/rnburn/rules_cc_module), but there's a lot of auxiliary files and stuff. I'm struggling with the syntax for a custom module mapping file - gcc keeps complaining whenever I try to reference iostream inside such a file. Do you have an example? I could see that some of the example projects import iostream.

Comment: You can look at their documentation [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/cxx-modules#CMI_Location). They describe the text format as one of the possible mappers.

Comment: @RyanBurn It does not describe the text format or how to use it. I have an [example](https://github.com/alexpanter/modules_testing/blob/master/gcc-testing/test_1E_module_mapping_file/myexe/module_mapper.txt). Whenever I reference iostream inside this file gcc complains, and I have tried a lot of permutations. Do you have any idea? I also cannot see any examples of how to use `$root` specified [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Module-Mapper.html).

Comment: Not sure. You could try gcc's [mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html) or IRC channel for help. But their module support is pretty buggy and incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

GCC 14 supports [P1689R5](https://wg21.link/p1689r5) output using the `-fdeps-file=$depoutput -fdeps-format=p1689r5` flags. Example:

```cpp
export module c;
import b;

export int c()
{
  return b();
}
```

```
$ g++ -E -fmodules-ts -MD -MF c.cxx.d -fdeps-file=/dev/stdout -fdeps-format=p1689r5 -fdeps-target=c.cxx.o c.cxx -o c.cxx.pp
```

will generate:

```json
{
"rules": [
{
"primary-output": "c.cxx.o",
"provides": [
{
"logical-name": "c",
"is-interface": true
}
],
"requires": [
{
"logical-name": "b"
}
]
}
],
"version": 0,
"revision": 0
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not know any way for gcc to do it, but i would suggest writing a helper script that expands the file and looks for everything named `import`, then you might need to sort imports using `"` and `<` and output them as headers.

Then you need to find which files exporting the selected module to match that with your import. That is you need to go through the expanded files and find statements beginning with `export module`.

You expand files with

```sh
g++ -E {include flags, standard version etc} > tmpfile
```

`-E` works with clang++ aswell, but for msvc you need `/E`

If there is a direct way to do this with gcc I would also be interested to know, but the question then arises: How do gcc know where to look for the modules?

On the contrary if you have a build system that keeps track of where each module is located you can specify that as with compile commands. (With clang you specify this with `-fmodule-file=` i think it is the same with gcc, but have not tested). At least that is how I have done in [my build system](https://github.com/Laserskold/matmake2).

But to summarize my answer to your question.
I think you need to:

- Expand your source files
- Find all files with `import`, `export import` and `export module` in them and process them.