# Using C++ Modules in Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, c++20, c++-modules

I want to use the new modules feature in C++20 and as far as I understand it, both gcc and clang seem to implement enough of it to be usable.

Now, basically all code-examples I see online compile all modules separately and manually specify their order.
Is there a way for `make` to automatically find the dependencies between different modules?

I would love to write a `Makefile` that basically looks like this:

```
# ...

SRC    := $(find $(SRCDIR) -name "*.cpp")
OBJ    := $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
PCM    := $(SRC:.cpp=.pcm)

*.pcm: CXXFLAGS += -Xclang -emit-module-interface

# ...

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
  $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(OBJ): %.o: %.cpp %.pcm
   $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(PCM): %.pcm: %.cpp
   $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

But this obviously doesn't work because `make` does not know in which order the modules need to be compiled.

So:

- What is the correct way to have a generic Makefile that works with C++ modules?
- Is there a good example for a non-trivial project using C++ modules and `make`?

Additionally:

- Is there a good example for a non-trivial project using C++ modules and `cmake`?

Comment: Requests for external resources ("Is there a good example for [...]") are off topic on SO.  The aspects of the question about writing makefiles that discover and account for module dependencies are on-topic, but not really specific to `make`.  If there are tools / compiler options that can capture the needed information then makefiles can very likely be constructed that capture and use that information, so it is first and foremost about whether tools -- probably the compiler, but possibly external tools -- can capture the needed info.

Comment: GCC appears to stick with the old "dumb toolchain" architecture, where the compiler doesn't know anything about the linker and the build tool, the linker doesn't know anything about the compiler and the build tool, and the build tool doesn't know anything about the compiler and the linker. You'd need a hack here like `gcc -MM` for headers.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66542797/is-there-a-way-to-query-direct-module-dependencies-with-gcc