# auto generate dependencies for modules

Tags: c++, module, dependencies, gnu-make, c++20

I start currently to understand [modules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules)

If we want to use `import <iostream>;` instead of old style `#include <iostream>` we need to "precompile" the `iostream` header file. We can do it manually by simply invoking g++ with:

> g++ -xc++-system-header  -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts iostream

But this needs a manually created set of rules for all used system header files for `gnu make` with all the dependencies pointing to the `gcm.cache` directory structure.

In case of old style `#include` directives, we simply have the `-M` or `-MM` flags to generate such dependencies for `make` automatically.

Q: How we can get such dependencies from `g++` for *imported modules* automatically to set up the rules for `gnu make`?

The target is quite simple: Get all needed `.gcm` files precompiled before the build system needs these files for import.

Comment: Just FTR (and to note that [`-MMD` can track modules](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Module-Preprocessing.html), too): https://stackoverflow.com/a/69604600/1479945