# How do I generate precompiled files for modules and header-units using gcc and make?

Tags: c++, gcc, gnu-make, c++-modules

If I have a source file like

```
import <iostream>;
import <array>;

import modA; 

int main() {}
```

how do I generate a dependency list to precompile all header-units `<iostream>` and `<array>` and also for the module `modA`?

If I try to use the `-MMD` option as this

```
/usr/local/bin/g++ -c -MMD -std=c++23 -fconcepts -fmodules-ts test400.cc
```

I get

```
/usr/local/include/c++/14.0.0/iostream: error: failed to read compiled module: No such file or directory
/usr/local/include/c++/14.0.0/iostream: note: compiled module file is 'gcm.cache/./usr/local/include/c++/14.0.0/iostream.gcm'
/usr/local/include/c++/14.0.0/iostream: note: imports must be built before being imported
/usr/local/include/c++/14.0.0/iostream: fatal error: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue
```

But adding option `-MG` also gives an error:

```
/usr/local/bin/g++ -c -MMD -MG -std=c++23 -fconcepts -fmodules-ts test400.cc      
error: '-MG' may only be used with '-M' or '-MM'
```

So, looks like i'm stuck now.

Any hints?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should never need to have dependencies on system headers (or modules). If and when they change, you have likely much bigger changes (like new compiler) so it would make sense to do a full rebuild then anyway.

Comment: That does not answer the question: initially I have to create the files. And also for local modul files and also for own libraries.

Comment: I had the same question without any valid answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190433/auto-generate-dependencies-for-modules Seems to be a lag of compiler support. I expect the same internal log as for -M and -MM with the modules to auto generate the rule set. But currently, it simply is not supported by gcc nor clang